# How to tell spam-assassin not to quarantine tagged emails?

Tags: postfix, freebsd, spamassassin, dovecot, amavis

I'm running my own postfix mail-server at home with a setup similar to [this one](http://workaround.org/articles/ispmail-etch/). I opted to deliver tagged spam via dovecot to the user's spam-mailbox, so that they can review tagged emails if they wish to; these spam-mailboxes get purged regularly and SA's bayes is trained on them.

The thing that's annoying though is that SA (or amavisd-new, I'm not even sure on that) additionally saves the tagged spam to /var/virusmails/spam-xxx.gz, which I don't want. I cannot find the correct option in the configuration to turn that behavior off.

Any pointers well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to set $QUARANTINEDIR to empty in amavisd.conf

```
# Location to put infected mail into: (applies to 'local:' quarantine method)
#   empty for not quarantining, may be a file (Unix-style mailbox),
#   or a directory (no trailing slash)
#   (the default value is undef, meaning no quarantine)
#
$QUARANTINEDIR = '/var/virusmails';
```

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I want (but that's probably to my sloppy question). Defining $QUARANTINEDIR to empty also stops viruses etc. to be quarantined. However, when looking for the documentation of this variable, I found that setting $spam_quarantine_method to `undef` does what I want.